# Match stock tickers in the text with a list of stock tickers without matching the stop words

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, text-classification

I have a python list with around 28,000 stock tickers.

I'm parsing through text which I scraped to match with the stock tickers and increase the count whenever I get a match.

The issue I am having is all the stop words are matching with some of the tickers which I don't want; eg V is a legitimate ticker and is matching with the individual tokenized words as it is free flowing social media text. eg V want TSLA.

Could you suggest me some logic where I could apply some logical smart matching with using these stop words?

```
counts = dict()
Symbol_list =['TSLA','V','T','AAPL',...]

example sentence = { 'V want TSLA but not. T + 5 times' }
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
sen = example_sentence.translate(str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation))

sentence_words = sen.split()
for words in sentence_words:
    if(word in symbol_list):
        counts[word] = counts.get(word,0) + 1
```

I would like to have `{'TSLA':1}` but not `{'TSLA':1, 'V':1, 'T': 1}`.
There might be some instances where I might need T and V to be added to the dictionary but contextually.

Comment: I don't see simple method. How is he supposed to know that one time you don't need `V` and `T` and other time you need `V` and `T` ? Even I don't know it. Maybe you will have to create complex system of `if/else` to skip  `V` and `T` in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
counts = dict()
example_sentence = { 'V want TSLA but not. T + 5 times' }
counts = dict()
symbol_list =['TSLA','V','T','AAPL',...]
example_sentence = 'V want TSLA but not. T + 5 times'
sen = example_sentence.translate(str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation))
sentence_words = sen.split()
counts_list = []
for word in sentence_words:
    if(word in symbol_list):
        counts[word] = counts.get(word,0) + 1
        counts_list.append({word:counts[word]})
```

Now you have as output a list of dictionaries:
counts_list[1]
{'TSLA': 1}